# An exercise on uncountable subsets of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am stuck on how to prove these three questions, or even how to draw the sets so I can see where they overlap.  Any help would be appreciated!

> 1. Let $C\subseteq [0,1]$ be uncountable. Show there exists a in $(0,1)$ such that $C\cap[a,1]$ is uncountable.
> 2. Let $A$ be the set of all $a \in (0,1)$ such that $C\cap[a,1]$ is uncountable, and set $p=\sup A$ Is $C\cap[p,1]$ an uncountable set?
> 3. Does question 1. remain true if "*uncountable*" is replaced by "*infinite*"?

Comment: Avoid using help please in the title. Edit the title into something containing the word (un)countable.

Comment: Hint for #1: suppose not, and consider rational numbers $a$; argue that then $C$ must be countable.

Comment: [Deleting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644587/real-analysis-sets-uncountable-interval-question) and re-posting a closed question to get rid of a downvote is not cool.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is there a canonical way to deal with this sort of behavior? (reopening the older one and migrating this one there, maybe?)

Comment: @Clement: Generally, I guess, alerting the moderators so they can make sure a user is not doing that repeatedly. The correct way to resolve the problem of the previous question would have been by editing it to include some context (as suggested by the closure banner) which may or may not have resulted in the question being reopened.

Comment: OK. I hadn't seen the older one (3 days ago), so it wasn't obvious to me this was a duplicate (it does not seem to show in the "Related" side panel, at least I didn't see it). (Not certain this says a lot of good about the recommendation system used by Math.SE, as it appears parts of the question were copied verbatim.)

Comment: @Clement: If you're not sure, treat it as a new question. And vote to close it, if the question deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for 1:** By contradiction. Start by observing that $C\setminus\{0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left( \left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]\cap C\right)$ (and $C\setminus\{0\}$ is uncountable).

**Hint for 2:** By contradiction, suppose $[p, 1]\cap C$ is uncountable. Can you apply the above argument (i.e., question 1) to $C^\prime = [p, 1]\cap C$ and $I=[p,1]$, instead of $C$ and $[0,1]$?

**Hint for 3:** take $C= \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast\}$.

Comment: I don't think your hint for 2 leads to a complete answer: it gives one counterexample, but the question is not "is $C \cap [p,1]$ *always* uncountable?"

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I had a wrong answer in mind. Fixed the hint (as well as what I had in mind).

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If for every $a = \frac{1}{n} \in (0,1)$, where $n \in \mathbb N$ we would have $C \cap \left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]$ countable then union $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C \cap [1/n, 1] = C \cap \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1/n, 1] = C \cap [0,1] = C-\{0\}$$

would be countable, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Should the second last step be $C \cap (0,1]$?